# xcode4 : how to call an action from another view?

Tags: iphone, xcode

lets say i have a mainView, from it i pushed to subView.

i can send value from subView to mainView by this code

```
mainView *main = [[mainView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
main.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:main animated:YES];
```

this code well send a textfield value from subView To mainView

```
NSString *text1 = field1.text;

[[mainView label1] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)text1]];
```

what if i have an action called action1 in mainView and i want to call it when i come back from subView ? what is the code for that ?

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your subView (where you want to call) put

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"uniqueName" object:anyObjectYouWantToPassToMain];
```

In your mainView (viewDidLoad) put

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethodName:) name:@"uniqueName" object:nil];
```

Your main will call the method `yourMethodName` when the postNotification is executed.

Comment: thanx for ur help ,, the code worked perfectly, i just changed it to [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"uniqueName" object:nil];

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question. When pushing another viewController, and wanting to return information to the controller that pushed it, the recommended ways is to declare a delegate protocol for the second view controller, and declare your first view controller to implement that delegate. The delegate method is one that simply passed the information back to the first view controller for it to deal with.

If you want to see a simple example of this at work, I wrote as small sample project a while ago that you can download.  [Delegation Example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/DelegationExample.zip).